# Can we do anything to avoid losing Bill D?

Tags: discussion, policy

Recently I was *very* disturbed to learn that one of the most distinguished members of the MSE community (my former teacher, and close friend, Prof. Bill D) was suspended for 30 days, under what seems to me to be very questionable circumstances. Does the MSE community support this? BD has selflessly volunteered much of his life to carefully teaching mathematics to high standards - which is evident in his many rich contributions to MSE.

Does the MSE community think that it is fair that a moderator should be able to wield such tremendous power, completely unchecked? Since BD has been openly (constructively) critical of various moderation policies, it seems to me that there is great potential that some bias was exhibited in imposing such a drastic suspension (which afaik is unprecedented on MSE.)

I think it would be a tremendous loss if Bill leaves MSE. Unfortunately this seems to be highly likely from what I hear through the grapevine. Perhaps the MSE community can rally together to find some compromise that avoids this lose-lose scenario, and to figure out better ways to manage conflicts, so to help prevent such problems from arising in the future (recall also the similar sad loss of Robin Chapman, another stellar contributor).

Perhaps we could be so lucky to get them both back to MSE? In any case, it would be a shame to waste the chance of preventing another such loss. What can we do?

[BD has not seen this post, nor do I know if he would approve it, but I could not think of any better way to help find a solution other than posting here. I abbreviate his name in hope of saving him any further embarrasment. I recall that generally it is discouraged to mention specific names on matters like these, but there seems to be no other way to properly address this particular matter.]

---

**Edit (1/24)** Please note that there are $9$ votes *not* to close in a comment below. So why was the question closed? Is this MathOverflow convention not respected here?

The community *can* rectify this grave injustice if only it speaks. Letting such injustice stand sets a dangerous precendent. Is that *truly* what the community desires? Please speak up. Re-open the question and let your voice be heard. It is *your* community and *you* can (and *should*) ensure that decisions are made in a way that represent the best interest of the community. Decisions on delicate matters like this should most certainly not be mechanically decided based on generic SE policy. Rather they should be governed by what is in the best interest of *this* community.

Already Robin Chapman is lost. So to is T.., and so too (almost) Pete L. Clark. Now you risk losing BD. Who's next, Arturo? If this trend continues the site will have tremendous difficulty attracting further senior members, let alone holding on to the few who remain. Is that what *you* desire?

Comment: I vote against closing this post. First, I am also interested in knowing what the "community" thinks about the suspension. Secondly, I am puzzled that the post has been voted to close without any explanation whatsoever. Personally, I think this is a constructive way to approach the obvious recent friction in the system; if someone disagrees, I would like to at least hear them out.

Comment: [See this answer.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/833/72)

Comment: @Isaac That answer does not appear to be relevant here, since  my question is not *why* he was suspended.

Comment: @MathGems: "Does the MSE community support this?" is impossible to answer given the information we have and it's impossible to address your implications that the suspension was unfounded without more information.  No such information is likely to be forthcoming.  Specifically, that answer says, "In general, it is a private matter between the moderators and that particular user. We leave it up to that user to discuss (or not discuss) what happened to them." which is directly applicable here.

Comment: @Isaac I have seen all the comments in the thread. Only one final comment by Bill was deleted (at his request I am told). In my opinion that comment certainly did not merit any kind of suspension (I've seen  *much* worse here), let alone a 30- day suspension. One can't help but be suspicious that the suspension has to do with BD's prior critiques of moderation.

Comment: @MathGems: Regardless of *your opinion* that this may have had something to do with criticizing the moderators, *I* can certainly help being suspicious.  I've been here through at least two and I think more attempted discussions like this and they are not constructive, in large part because they are lacking in substantive information and heavy on supposition and personal opinion.

Comment: @Isaac From the perspecitive of a former moderator, do you think such a harsh suspension was fair? Speaking as someone who has moderated in other forums, my goal is always to attempt to defuse the matter in a way that will have minimal long-lasting consequences - not in one that may drive away valued community members.

Comment: @MathGems: Such a suspension is standard on SE sites, as mentioned in Zev's answer.  It is not always possible to defuse a situation and simultaneously avoid driving away valued community members—the majority (perhaps all) of the longer suspensions that I'm aware of here had to do with sustained patterns of behavior that had already lead to previous suspensions with no resulting change in behavior.

Comment: @Isaac Why do you think information is lacking: the [comment thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/101506/23500) is easily locatable by looking at BDs activity. Nothing there comes close to warranting a 30 day suspension. IMO there is clear bias.

Comment: @MathGems: Because we don't all know what comments have been deleted, either by moderators or by the system (a certain number of flags automatically deletes a comment, leaving no visible trace behind, even for moderators), and because we don't have any substantive information on past history.

Comment: The skeptic deep within me is _screaming_ for this to be pointed out:  So you made your account _directly_ after BD's suspension, but yet somehow have an extensive knowledge of over a year an half's worth of activity on these meta forums?  The two questions you answered are exactly BD's type, and written in his style.  Most shocking is your English.  Writing is unique to a person, and I have read enough of BD's forum posts to say this _feels_ like his writing, and noone elses.  I may be wrong, but I'll also go on a huge hunch, (almost like the basis of this question..) and say **you are BD**.

Comment: @Eric I would be delighted if I could somehow get BD to post here, since my memory is not perfect. But until then you'll have to settle for my third-hand accounts.  I do understand your skepticism.

Comment: @Eric Oh, and thanks for the compliments. But neither can I teach like Bill, nor do I have extensive knowledge of this site. I created a new account since I don't want to get my primary account entangled in this mess.

Comment: @Isaac There is only one comment that was deleted (at BDs request). Having seen it (a screen grab),  I doubt most readers would agree that it merits a 30-day suspension. Iirc it is a remark by BD that he doesn't believe that P appreciates certain issues involved in teaching number theory. Is it slightly rude? Perhaps so by the standards of this site. But having also taught number theory, I can understand Bill's frustration given P's prior remarks. It is difficult to truly grasp many of these matters unless one has significant experience teaching these topics.

Comment: @Dan: You're right, I've deleted all relevant comments and sent a private message to the user Math Gems.

Comment: But I'm no longer Abel to continue this conversation... :)

Comment: @Eric: That's just not Bill's style.

Comment: @MathGems: I think you missed my point—you claim you saw it and there was only one comment; I (and presumably everyone else, but I can only speak for myself) have no way to verify your claim, nor any verifiable way to see the comment(s) that were deleted.  Further, I have no way of knowing for certain what other context might be relevant here—past warnings, details of past suspensions, etc.  The net effect of this is that I do not have enough information to engage in a discussion of the appropriateness of the suspension and this question is not constructive.

Comment: @Isaac According to BD, there are no such past warnings over the past year. I can email you the full comment thread (screen grab). In any case, it's your prerogative to decide that you don't have enough info. But why are you seemingly so invested in stifling the discussion, rather than letting the community speak freely?

Comment: @MathGems: Again, because it is my opinion that *this discussion is not helpful* and that it is likely actively harmful to the community.

Comment: @Isaac I see no "harm" anywhere here. Openness is something that one should strive for in community governed sites. But this is getting way off-topic, so let's drop it, ok?

Comment: @MathGems: For someone who has been a member here for all of 2 days, I wouldn't expect you to see the harm.

Comment: I've been here much longer (on and off), and I've been on many similar forums for quite a long time. Again, please stay on topic.

Comment: @Math, since you are an experienced forum user, it should be no surprise to you that your opinions don't carry much weight (based on your level of involvement). I don't want BD to leave either, but a meta question isn't the best way to effect change.

Comment: @TheChaz Try as I may, the only way I could see to attempt to right this wrong is to attempt to rally the support of the community. It seems, hoever, that many members are hesitant to get involved in such matters. Unfortunately, without such, the "brain drain" will continue unchecked.

Comment: Math Gems, I have voted up this question; I also voted Srivatsan's comment. However after seeing Isaac's answer I am convinced that there is an importance of bringing this to the community (that is the fact that Bill was suspended for such a period) and I completely  agree that anything I say about the topic comes from an incomplete point of view. I know **too little** on the details and cannot give any useful input. Zev answered and he's a moderator, this counts (for me) as an official reply and further communications should be made privately via emails.

Comment: FWIW, the "official" process of suspensions is detailed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23681

Comment: @Mariano Thanks. According to that Bill should have received at most a 1-7 day suspension, since, from what I know, he was never before suspended for "behaviors identified in stage 1". I don't think he was ever officially even warned in stage 1 afaik. **So yet more evidence that was probably bias behind this unjust suspension.**

Comment: To respond to the Edit: I am still here.  I did temporarily quit at one point out of pique with "Stack Overflow Valued Associate #00001", but after sober consideration the positive aspects of participation here outweighed the negative and I came back.  (And FWIW, #00001 seems to have cooled down quite a bit in the interim.)  I have no strong opinion on this suspension issue for similar reasons to the others: I do not have access to all the relevant information.  But do I trust the moderators to act reasonably?  Yes, I do -- in fact they are the people I *trust most* when it comes to this...

Comment: @Math Gems: From Bill's "dossier": **Feb 11, 2011:** Official warning given. Requested that (i) the user be more civil (ii) the user does not bring up past interactions with other users on other fora (iii) the user not to delete answers to shed downvotes. Further violation will result in suspension. **Feb 28, 2011:** User suspended for 2 days for spiteful downvoting together with a previous history of troublesome behavior. **Jan 23, 2012**: User suspended for 30 days for being abusive to others. Why don't you talk that over with Bill and see what he says.

Comment: For everyone's information, there is now currently one vote to delete this thread. [The question would currently require a total of 5 votes to delete from 10k+ users for it to be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071). Please vote on this comment if you support the deletion of this thread and for all further discussion between Math Gems, Bill Dubuque, and the moderators to occur via email.

Comment: Please vote on this comment if you oppose the deletion of this thread.

Comment: I think this thread should stay closed and *locked*, but not deleted, for documentation purposes.

Comment: @Zev I am shocked that you, as a moderator, are proposing outright censorship by proposing that the thread be deleted. You should instead be lurking in the background, *neutral*, listening to your community speak, not trying to strongly discourage such. Please go to your library and read something about basic mediation principles.

Comment: I am asking the community's opinion about the deletion of this thread. Did you notice that I presented both options and did not state any opinion about which one I preferred? If 5 different 10k+ users determine that it is best for the community if this thread is deleted, so be it. I, however, am not shocked that you would claim I am attempting to "censor" you.

Comment: @Zev Your are *strongly* biasing the discussion by participating in this way. Can't you see that comments like yours and Isaac's will make other users very uncomfortable to speak up? Many who could have contributed constructive advice and made your job easier.

Comment: You know, I don't think I have to go to my library to know that telling someone "go to your library and read something about basic mediation principles" ***is not in any book on basic mediation principles***. Maybe I'm just psychic.

Comment: @MathGems: That is a distortion of what happened.  Zev has provided an outlet for the community to give input on whether deletion should be supported or opposed.  Since the software does not allow direct "voting-against-deleting," this is actually in the opposite direction of what you are accusing.

Comment: @Jonas Moderators should not be attempting to influence the community's voice. There was no other community member who proposed deletion or anything close to that.

Comment: Moreover, who votes on which comment is something we mods cannot know. *So neither you, Math Gems, nor anyone should be afraid of **what we can do to you** if you vote for one of the two options provided by Zev's comments, for we cannot know what comments you voted!*

Comment: @MathGems: Your sentence, "There was no other community member who proposed deletion or anything close to that," is plainly false, as was noted in the first sentence of Zev's comment which reads, "For everyone's information, there is now currently one vote to delete this thread."  The vote referred to was, unsurprisingly, made before Zev made that comment.

Comment: @zev Obviously that was friendly advice. In my experience, learning mediation by the seat of your pants is never very successful. There are many good books written on mediation, e.g. see the classic [Getting to Yes](http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Yes-Negotiating-Agreement-Without/dp/0143118757) to start with.

Comment: @Jonas Right. We also have no disproof that such a vote was not made by Zev or a mod. In any case, imo, mods should not be trying to accelerate any process (e.g. deletion) to stifle community feedback. It seems to me that at least a couple mods are actively working at getting this thread closed and deleted.

Comment: @Math Gems: A mod's vote to delete would have taken instantaneous effect. So, actually, we **do** have proof that it was not me nor any other mod.

Comment: @Zev Not if it were a former mod like Isaac. The point is that the deletion vote was probably by one of the two most vocal critics here - you or Isaac, current or former mods. In any case, I respectfully request that you honor that question that I asked, and please refrain from further derailing focus from the main issues.

Comment: As I said before, what do you consider to be the "main issues" if not 1: the reasons for Bill's suspension, 2: an explanation of the accountability of the site moderators, 3: your accusations that all moderators past and present (as well as many other highly ranked users) are engaged in a conspiracy against Bill?

Comment: @MathGems: Former mods are not mods. The fact that there is a vote that is not binding *does* establish that the vote was not cast "by Zev or a mod". I honestly think you are misinterpreting Zev's pair of comments; had he not spoken up, the votes to delete would have been essentially silent (and invisible to users without sufficient rep, if I remember correctly) and as soon as 5 users with sufficient rep voted to delete, it would have been deleted. By soliciting upvotes in comments (which requires less rep) he is polling lower rep users and getting "opposed-to-delete" 'votes'.

Comment: Arturo is exactly correct about my intentions and the mechanics of the site.

Comment: @Math Gems: I claim that ***you're*** derailing the discussion. What do you have to say about my evidence that the moderators followed the advised suspension process to the letter?

Comment: @Arturo I suppose one can look at it either way, glass half-empty or half-full.

Comment: @Zev BD says the information is not correct. As I said below, I am no longer going to pursue this avenue since it does not seem to be an efficient way to accomplish my goals. Again, thanks to all who contributed. Bye.

Comment: @Math Gems: Aw, but what about all the "main issues" I was derailing the focus from? I was waiting with bated breath to find out what they were! In any case, email the moderators if you'd like screenshots & copies of relevant emails demonstrating that the moderators acted in compliance with the suspension guidelines.

Comment: @MathGems Please stop pretending that you are some kind of representative of the community. Your edit and your comments suggest that you seem to think that the majority of the community shares your opinions but is too afraid of the evil, all-powerful moderators' wrath. The community has plenty of ways of expressing consent of otherwise by voting on comments, answers, etc. So kindly let everyone speak for himself and try to keep the polemics and the unwarranted accusations down. P.S. I am not a mod, I have never been one, nor do I intend to become one, in case any of this matters to you.

Comment: Wow, this thread has turn complete soap opera in the three hours since I last checked it, and I fear what will be in the morning. Math Gems, Zev only acted in *your* favor allowing this thread to continue and made public the "secret" fact that there is a standing deletion vote. I should also point out that as time goes by your taste for hyperboles seem to grow bigger, whether it's you or me it seems that the melodrama is exponential. Soon we'll require some deus ex machina to correct things. Please stop that, I am all in favor arguing for Bill, but your attitude makes things worse. Stop that.

Comment: @Asaf Please see alsewhere, I have already thrown in the towel. Perhaps if the mods had remained in the background and let the community speak then we might have been able to learn something about what the community truly thinks. But now it is hopeless, since the thread has been derailed by too many tangential topics.

Comment: You should understand, though. The moderators *are* part of the community. They are not some external admins, they are people that works hard to be recognized and were elected *by* the community. This means that not only they have a vote of confidence from the community, but also that their opinions are valid as members of the site just as my opinion is valid, just as yours is valid. Talking in superlatives and claiming that everyone that speaks against you has some bias is just wrong.

Comment: @Asaf Please read what I wrote elsewhere here (and see the book I referenced for some references to research on mediation).

Comment: For reference, I *cannot* have been the delete vote because for the first 48 hours after a question is closed, only users with at least 20k reputation can vote to delete.

Comment: Also, any user with 3k or more reputation can vote to close or reopen.  5 such users (me and 4 others) voted to close.  Thus far, no one has voted to reopen.  There are at least 130 users who could vote to reopen, having at least 3k reputation and not having voted to close and not being moderators.

Comment: About moderators' hostility towards Bill Dubuque: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1724/1 .

Comment: @Lovre: Qiaochu decided to [remove that comment later](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1724/264). But I doubt it is only moderators who find toxic the *behavior* of a user who repeatedly downvoted answers competing with his own and proceeded to assign blame to "poor software design decisions". Please do make sure to read the [entire thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720). Of course, Bill's mathematical contributions have been extremely valuable to the site, and for the most part we all get along quite well in fact, with many constructive discussions;

Comment: it is only the occasional issue where things blow up. ***Note also that your link confirms Bill received a warning, then received a suspension of between 1 to 7 days***, and then (as we are all now amply aware) was suspended for 30 days just recently. [***This is exactly the recommended suspension procedure***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23681), as Mariano pointed out above. This should settle the grandiose claims of injustice and bias once and for all.

Comment: @Zev: I know that, but the comment has only been removed from the current revision of the post, but it is still public and Qiaochu hasn't, to my knowledge, apologised for such comments.
Also, I don't see the basis for claim that Bill "repeatedly downvoted answers competing with his own", as he has almost 1400 answers, and only 134 downvotes -- other users also baselessly accused Bill of downvoting from spite, when it is apparent that Bill has his own view of pedagogy and how mathematics should be taught...

Comment: ... and while his tone has often been argumentative, I have never seen him behave in an uncivil manner. Anyway, I do not want to play a role of Bill's defender; I have only stated my opinion about this case and posted what I saw as a relevant post, and I do not wish to engage in further discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @Lovre: There is no way for anyone to remove previous versions of posts. Also, Bill only engaged in this activity for a short time before he was suspended for it, and he may have decided to reverse those downvotes since then. The accusations were not baseless - the people involved tracked Bill's downvote count as events unfolded, and while there is no definitive way of proving anything (even moderators cannot see who downvoted what), the correlation was convincing enough for everyone else to agree about what was going on.

Comment: @Lovre: Sorry, I just now see your latest post - thanks for your input and hopefully I have addressed some of your concerns.

Comment: @Zev The comment cited by Lovre, where Qiaochu Yuan wrote that "he and the other mods find Bill's presence toxic" is not only far more uncivil than anything that Bill has ever said, but it is also clear evidence of moderator bias. I am told that there were similar uncivil comments by Willie Wong, now deleted. And what of the *very uncivil* comment above by Eric - which is quite insulting to both Bill and I? Why allow that to stand when it too is far more uncivil than the comment for which Bill was suspended? Yet you wonder why I consider this to be very unjust treatment of my revered teacher.

Comment: @Zev Further, why do you insist on interpreting that prior event in the most sinister way possible even after the truth of the matter has already been explained elsewhere here? Your interpretation does not fit the facts of the matter. Moreover, your continued campaign to portray Bill in the worst possible way only serves to support my prior claims of moderator bias - whether subconscious or not.

Comment: @Math Gems: Why do you insist on interpreting every action the moderators have ever taken in the most sinister way possible, even after the truth of the matter has already been explained elsewhere here? Your interpretation does not fit the facts of the matter. Moreover, your continued campaign to portray the moderators in the worst possible way only serves to support my prior claims of pro-Bill bias - whether subconscious or not.

Comment: @Math Gems: Yes, it was uncivil. Qiaochu had the decency to remove it. However, you have not deleted any of the uncivil comments where you accuse me and the other moderators of the absolute lowest behavior possible - in particular, the ones which have already been demonstrated to be false, since Willie's suspension is perfectly within the guidelines of suggested suspension length. Moreover, you were told incorrectly, as there are no deleted comments from Willie present there.

Comment: @Lovre Thanks you for unearthing that comment - which clearly supports my claims of moderator bias. While Bill had showed me other examples, I was not aware of that instance.

Comment: @Zev  Again you have the facts incorrect: according to Bill (who is here now), Qiaochu did not "have the decency to remove" that hostile comment. Rather, Qiaochu removed it only after much pleading from Bill, after Bill pointed out that leaving it was not good for the health of the site. Would you please, please stop commenting on matters for which you don't know the facts. Your comments here are factually incorrect on many matters.

Comment: @MathGems: Why should we presume that, regarding any disputed fact(s), everything you say Bill says is true while everything that anyone else says is false?

Comment: @Isaac (1) There is a link above to the comment, so it is a fact. Try as you may, you cannot dispute that. (2) If you ask Qiaochu I trust that he will confirm that what I stated is true.

Comment: @Math Gems: Everyone who's here now, following this thread, can see that you don't have the decency to remove your hostile comment claiming that Willie's suspension of Bill was biased. Would you please, please stop commenting.

Comment: @Zev The evidence is plain as day for all to see. Thank you for helping to prove my point. My job is done. Bye.

Comment: @Math Gems: Bye bye!

Comment: I have voted to delete this entire tedious thread. Why should we allow the meta site to be overcome with a dramatic spectacle containing argumentative posts by an anonymous user with a new account?

Comment: @JDH You too are anonymous here to those who do not know what your initials denote. As I'm sure you are aware, there are many honorable reasons why one may choose anonymity on the net. Did you miss the 19 votes against deleting?

Comment: Bill, I am not anonymous, as my profile links directly to my name, affiliation and contact information.

Comment: @JDH My name is not Bill. And, at one point, you were anonymous here iirc.

Comment: No, that's not correct. I created my math.SE account profile to link to my MO user page from the start. But I shant engage any further on this thread, which as I have said I support deleting.

Comment: @JDH Well I do distinctly recall long ago wondering who JDH was, and not easily being able to ascertain such. Perhaps the links were not all in place then, or perhaps it was elsewhere. But this is far from the subject at hand.

Comment: I agree with JDH. Reportedly the moderators want to keep it for documentation purposes, but I'm not sure what purpose this serves. (After all, deleted posts aren't *really* deleted.)

Comment: This whole thing is hilarious.. some guy well over 50 behaving in a childish and cutthroat fashion against mainly college/grad students, getting suspended, then putting up a fake account to argue over the suspension. Bill: Grow up, get over it, do your time, and try to behave civilly in the future.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, deleted posts are not really deleted, but are only visible to a few people.

Comment: It is clear that this thread is no longer useful. I *emphatically* want to keep it around—I don't think there is anything to gain from editing the site into one where this interchange has not happened, and my experience online dealing with similar events tells me there is in fact a loss in doing that. In a second,I'll lock this thread. $${}$$I take here the opportunity to thank everyone who participated —commenting, voting, flagging (there were lots of flags!) or even only reading this— for, in all, it shows clearly that there is interest in the members of this community to make it better.

Answer (score 27):

I am offended by your accusation that any of the moderators acted out of retaliation for Bill's criticisms of the site's policies. As far as you indicate in your post, you have **no idea** what the circumstances are - you simply *assume* that they are very questionable. Perhaps it would have been more prudent to keep that assumption to yourself until the facts of the case came out.

Moreover, we are accountable to the StackExchange team; see the answers to [this meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99602/161783) for example.

As to the actual circumstances: Willie Wong suspended Bill for his comments on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101506/264), which were flagged as rude/offensive. Bill was suspended once before for this kind of behavior and more generally has a history of occasionally interacting uncivilly with other users. Of course, his contributions to math.SE have been immensely valuable, but that doesn't put him above the system. The *system-recommended* suspension length for the second serious issue is 30 days. I think there is room to  argue that Bill should have received a reduced sentence. But the kind of behavior displayed in that thread is inappropriate and should (and will) be met with a suspension regardless of the user who perpetrates it.

---

***In response to the recent edit:***

Firstly, votes to not close do not have any official status on math.SE, though as a new user (or, perhaps, "new user"?) I would not expect you to know that.

Secondly, there is only **one** vote to not close, with 9 people expressing their sympathy with at least one part of Srivatsan's comment - even the convention on MO is that only users who can vote to close are able to vote to not close, and no one else has explicitly done so.

Thirdly, closing questions **is a mechanism for** the community to let its voice be heard, while you're trying to portray it as anything but. In my opinion, and I'm sure many others' as well, closing this question (which is really more of a rant at this point) **is** in the best interest of the community.

Fourthly, your melodramatic language and talk of "grave injustice" is absurd, wins over no one, and devalues the many actual injustices that occur in this world. I am sure Bill will be able to survive not using this site for another 28 days.

Fifthly and finally, Robin Chapman and Pete Clark left due to conflicts with SE employees and your including them in this discussion is extremely disingenuous (I am not aware of why T. left).

Comment: No offense was intended. I happen to have much knowledge of these matters since I am a very close friend of BDs, and we have for many years discussed matters relating to sci.math, MSE, etc on a frequent basis.  I don't agree that the suspension was merited. Nor do I think that the majority of the community would agree with such if they saw what prompted it. IMO, having seen some of the personal emails that WW sent to BD (which you may have not), there can be no doubt that WW was biased when making such a decision. Due to recent prior strong words between them, WW should have recused himself.

Comment: Further, your information doesn't jibe with my memory, so I just spoke to Bill to verify it. He tells me that he was suspended once about a year ago, not having to do with uncivil comments, but rather due to an experiment with votes that went awry (he claims he gave up attempting to explain it to the then mods - perhaps he should have been more patient). So it seems that even the cited grounds are questionable.

Comment: Since it came up, here is a relevant reference for a previous suspension: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/downvoted-by-another-user-for-the-wrong-reasons

Comment: @jonas I recall discussing that matter with BD. If I recall correctly, he was temporarily experimenting with a way of placing up/down votes, to see if it could have any effect on working around deficiencies in the software. His code had a bug that was casting up votes as down votes, and he did not realize this till after the suspension (so his comments in that thread probably were written before he realized that many downvotes were mistakenly cast in error). I am probably forgetting some important details, so please don't quote me on that. So there was no "spiteful" votes.

Comment: @Math Gems: I do not need to quote you.  You are displaying all of this publicly.

Comment: @jonas I don't know what you mean by the above.

Comment: @MathGems: Perhaps I should have used a smiley to indicate that I was being whimsical.  I was responding to where you wrote "please don't quote me" about your descriptions which are already posted as an exact quote directly from you. :)  Please don't take it too seriously; I do understand the meaning of the expression.

Comment: @Zev I would like to clarify one point. Based on what I saw of WWs emails to BD, there is strong evidence that this prior history could easily lead to *subconscious* bias when WW made his decision. This is precisely why judges recuse themselves from cases. That is the sort of bias that I refer to - not your "acting out of retaliation". I don't know where you got that idea, but those words seem to be needlessly altering the tone of the discussion. Perhaps you could be so kind to edit your answer to more accurately reflect what I wrote, now that the intent is clear.

Comment: @Math Gems, "subconscious bias" alters the tone of the discussion in an entirely different way.  If there are some emails pertinent to the issue of moderation policy, please post them so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Dan Posting private emails in public without the consent of the authors is very poor netiquette. I cannot do that without the consent of both BD and WW. Probably BD would not mind, but I cannot speak for WW. But this was not my intent. Rather, I hoped that WW would realize that perhaps he did exhibit some subconscious bias and, perhaps, put his personal matters aside and reconsider the suspension from the more global perspective of its negative impact on the community.

Comment: @Math Gems, that is understandable.  I agree that the important issue is whether or not a 30-day suspension is appropriate in this situation (and in my opinion it is not).

Comment: @Zev In reply to your edit: Some highly valued members have left due to conflicts that could *easily* have been resolved by experienced mediators. There are surely some community members who do have such experience (I know at least one) But, for whatever reasons, they have not stepped up to help. It is essential that the community is actively involved in these matters. It is disturbing to see both current and former mods actively discouraging such. IMO, that does not bode well for the future of the site.

Comment: @Math Gems: None of the moderators have done **anything** here to discourage the involvement of the community, and the community **is** actively involved here - your post currently has 400 views and 25 votes. Understandably, you don't like it when the community is involved and the outcome is not exactly what you want.

Comment: @Zev False. I see one former moderator (Isaac) doing all he can to get the question closed as nonconstructive. I see another moderator (you) trying to shift the focus away from the main issues, and inflame matters by claiming that offensive things were said (which were not), etc. Do you have any professional experience mediating? Do any of the moderators? If not, then it would be wise to solicit input from those who do. All of the criticism in this thread is by current and former mods. That will make other members very fearful to  speak up. That is not the way to moderate *democratically*.

Comment: The question was closed by 5 people, of whom one was Isaac. I am sure you are not implying in any way the other four are of such poor judgement that they mindlessly followed suit? I have checked the IPs of those four users and they are different from Isaac's, so this is not a case of suckpuppetry, at least!

Comment: @Mariano Huh? I have no clue what your point is. That addresses nothing that I wrote.

Comment: You wrote that you saw Isaac doing all he can to get the question closed, but I observed that four other people —who we can assume acted out of their own free will— also voted to close. None of whom are or were moderators of the site, as far as I know.

Comment: FWIW: I am not a current or former moderator, and the input from the current and former moderators does not make me fearful.

Comment: @Math Gems: And what are the main issues, if not 1: the reasons for Bill's suspension, 2: an explanation of the accountability of the site moderators, 3: your accusations that all moderators past and present (as well as many other highly ranked users) are engaged in a conspiracy against Bill?

Comment: By the way, when I spend copious amounts of my free time helping the community and am accused of being as base as to attempt to stifle people who disagree with me, **I am offended**.

Comment: Dear Zev, I am grateful for both the time spent and for the quality of the moderation you do.  (Same goes for all of our community moderators.) Thank you.  Sincerely,

Comment: @Jonas: Thank you for your kind words. They are most welcome at a time when my patience is wearing thin.

Comment: @Zev If very actively working to close a discussion does not count as "stifling" it, then please do tell me what does.

Comment: @Mariano Most likely those who voted to close were influenced by the post of Isaac or Zev. That's my point. The mods were on a campaign to close it instead of *listening* to what the community wanted. That is a *cardinal sin* when it comes to moderation. I have little time left to devote to this, and the thread has already been derailed, so I see no point of continuing. There are other approaches I will pursue. **Thanks to all who contributed constructively.**

Comment: @Math Gems: In all of your experience moderating, were you ever granted mind control powers? I certainly wasn't. Your post was closed by 5 members of the community because it would "likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". That is ***exactly*** what has happened, and is continuing to happen, regardless of the closure. I say that demonstrates it ought to have been closed. If you think that that's not a good reason for closure, take it up with the SE team.

Comment: It was closed because it was derailed long before the community had a chance to speak.  Please do look up that book. It will greatly help you learn to mediate better, both here and in all aspects of life. Bye and best of luck.

Comment: This is almost nonsensical (a word which, surprisingly, is not caught by my spell-checker). I only just now caught this, but I wanted it down that in this exchange, I stand by Zev and the other moderators. I understand why he feels offended, and I credit his patience. While I understand that this might be construed as my 'being influenced... by a campaign to close' this thread, I say that would be an aggrandized claim.

Comment: @Zev I do appreciate the professionality with which you handle this. But imo "Math Gems" has expressed some *serious* accusations towards the moderator team that have not been adressed properly. His claim -- that BD's suspension has been catalysed by personal issues with one of the moderators -- may have seemed too laughable to seriously respond to it, but as far as I can tell a user has been suspended for 30 days for stating that someone has just lost the chance to learn from him -- it's hard to think of something more polite yet still insulting. [Continued...]

Comment: Given (a) the (apparent!) lack of proportionality, (b) the grave accusations brought up and (c) the fact that the suspending moderator has apparently made no effort to explain himself, I would appreciate if you could reassure me that and explain me how (1) the 'crime' is perfectly proportional to the punishment and in particular (2) this suspension is in no way related to any personal issues that may or may not have existed between WW and BD.

Comment: @Myself: Likewise, I appreciate the calm and reasonable tone you've taken - a model I hope "Math Gems" adopts in the future. Unfortunately, many of the relevant comments that led to Bill's suspension have by now been deleted, which vastly increases the apparent disproportionality. However, the issue (as I see it) was that Bill claimed that Paul's answer was incorrect, and while he obliquely indicated what he considered the problem to be (that one needs to explain that the fact that $2\mid ab$ and $2\nmid a$ implies $2\mid b$ depends on $2$ being prime),

Comment: he refused to say it explicitly and left Paul increasingly frustrated, because Paul considered this fact to be something low-level enough that it did not need to be stated explicitly (that each of them felt this way was not clear to the other). I think the turning point was when Bill said "If you handed that "proof" into my elementary number theory class you'd get zero credit." and "Alas, your remarks indicate that you have absolutely no clue what is essential to successfully teach (elementary) number theory." I consider this inappropriate, especially given the extremely minor nature of Paul's

Comment: "mistake". Together with Bill's history of incivility, I think this warrants *some* suspension. I cannot speak to Willie's state of mind, but I imagine he began the suspension process and observed that the recommended length for the second serious issue was 30 days. However, as I say in my post, I think there's room to argue that a smaller duration was more appropriate. Perhaps if "Math Gems" had asked that Bill's suspension be reduced, a moderator would have happily obliged and we'd all be dealing with less idiotic things than accusations of censorship, unchecked power, grave injustice, etc.

Comment: I think "Math Gems" would have been wise to learn from Bill's use of that tactic [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052) (probably one of the reasons why Bill and Willie have not been on the best of terms in the past). Hopefully I have allayed your concerns somewhat. I am sure that if you email Willie he will be happy to discuss this further with you.

Comment: @Myself Please see the comment of Lovre under the question for indisputable evidence of moderator bias. In case you may not be aware, Bill has frequently *constructively* criticized the moderation policy. This apparently sparked some hostile comments and emails from Willie Wong (the mod who recently unjustly suspended Bill). Note also that the thread is very close to being deleted, just as the truth is coming out. So much for freedom of speech.

Comment: @Myself Please see everything written by the user Math Gems for indisputable evidence of Math Gems' bias. In case you may not be aware, Bill has *also* frequently ***un*** constructively criticized the moderation policy. This apparently sparked some hostile comments and emails from Bill (the user who recently unjustly accused the moderators of stifling freedom of speech). Note also that the thread will not be deleted, since the moderators can overturn a deletion and we want to keep this thread as a record of Math Gems' (and our own) actions. So much for responsible use of freedom of speech.

Comment: @Zev That's great to here that the thread won't be deleted since it will be of great use for policy discussion the next time moderator elections are held.

Comment: @Math Gems: First of all, elections would only add to the ranks of the evil moderators - I don't plan on stepping down anytime soon. But I would be happy to run on my actions here - [take a look at the support I got in the comments here!](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-43821)

Comment: @Zev Again you have the facts wrong above. There are not "many deleted comments" by Bill. There is only one. As a mod you can see it. Why do you insist on distorting the truth? Since you do not play fair, I will no longer continue this discussion. You exhausted my patience long ago.

Comment: @Math Gems: There are three, two of which are the ones I quoted to the user Myself. As I moderator I can see it and [post screenshots of it to disprove you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iOttC.png). Why do you insist on distorting the truth? Even though you do not play fair, I will be happy to continue this discussion anytime, anywhere.

Comment: @Zev No, there is only *one* comment deleted by Bill, so again you are wrong. Thanks for (finally!) posting the full comment thread. Now everyone can judge for themselves the appropriateness of the suspension.

Comment: @Math Gems: I said that the comments "have by now been deleted". I didn't claim they were deleted by Bill. Were those (multiple) comments what got Bill in trouble? Yes. Were they deleted? Yes. You are wrong.

Comment: No, you wrote above "MANY of the relevant comments that led to Bill's suspension have by now been deleted" when in fact you knew that there was only one. Since you continue to distort the facts, I am through. The readers now have enough information to see the truth plain as day. Thank you for providing that. Best of luck come next election!

Comment: @Math Gems: Hilarious! You say "finally" as if you'd been clamoring for it all along. And I think the scores on all of the posts here demonstrates how people have judged the appropriateness of the suspension.

Comment: @Math Gems: Thanks! Tell Bill I wish him luck too, if he'd like to run for moderator and show us all how it's done.

Answer (score 12):

The comment thread became slightly uncivil but I think a 30-day suspension is too harsh.  That is a long enough time for a person to find entirely different hobbies and it is sure to make one feel unwelcome.  Perhaps it is an appropriate way to deal with a person posting profanity or plagiarism but that is not the case here.

Certainly established and valued users should be subject to the same standards as everyone else, but maybe the standards should be changed?  Why 30 days and not e.g. 3?

Comment: Ignoring this specific situation, I believe it's fairly standard for a second suspension from an SE site to be 30 days (as a partial answer to your "why" question).  ***edit*** my recollection as to the source on this was incorrect; it had been suggested to me some time ago that the suspensions should progress 2 days, 7 days, 30 days, 1 year.

Comment: It would make sense for this escalation to be reset periodically.  I've never been suspended but I've occasionally behaved in ways that might have warranted it and I would guess the same is true for most of us.  If the counter is never reset then I imagine everyone is guaranteed to strike out eventually after some number of years.

Comment: As a fairly new member of this community, I believe given BD's reputation, 30-day is indeed too harsh. But disagree about finding "different hobbies". (Surely math must be life for a mathematician!) Going back to length, reason why 30 day is because in this line of field, even a day can stunt progress. (Again I am not cognizant of the details of what rights are taken away ie if suspension is of IP?). I for one feel a community would be more productive from his input than an isolated case of him 'losing it' which caused his suspension.

Comment: @Mahmud, if I were to be suspended for 30 days I might very well take up knitting in the interim and never return again.  I'm somewhat impulsive and attention-deficient so I'm sure this doesn't apply to everyone.  But I also suspect many of us are repelled by rejection.

Comment: I have no idea where to leave this comment, but I certainly agree that 30 days is too long. As a student, I find Bill's answers to be some of the most enlightening. I can't comment on what transpired, but the idea of 30 days without such beautiful, elegant, and elucidating answers is quite sad (IF he comes back?).

Answer (score 6):

No one, except possibly the suspended user and possibly the moderators and administrators of the site, can be certain that they have complete knowledge of this type of situation.  Given that and given that previous such discussions (and there have been previous such discussions) have not been constructive, I do not think this is a constructive approach to the situation.  In saying that, I feel compelled to suggest a potential alternative approach.  It is possible to contact the site administration via the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, which is a `mailto:` link.  When you believe that moderator(s) have acted inappropriately, I think that contacting the site administration is the most constructive possible course of action.

Comment: I can email you the screen grab that I saw that proves what I wrote. The mods can confirm that only that one comment has been deleted. They would have corrected me by now if it were false. I'm perplexed why you seem to want to imply that there is more to the matter than is true. In full disclosure, perhaps you should reveal that you too were once a moderator. Please keep in mind that your opinions on this matter are no doubt colored by your analogous moderator experiences, perhaps with BD or other users.

Comment: @MathGems: It's entirely possible that there were other comments that were removed automatically by user flags, which neither you nor the moderators saw.  I'm not implying there's more to the matter, but I am explicitly stating that it is *not possible* for me to have enough information for certain to have a constructive discussion about whether the suspension was warranted or not and I am suggesting that it is equally impossible for nearly anyone else to have enough information either.

Comment: @MathGems: Also, to be clear, I have not said if I agree or disagree with your assessment of the situation as fair or unfair.  What I have consistently said is that we (the community as a whole, but myself specifically) lack the information to constructively engage in this type of conversation about *any* suspended user *ever*.  My opinion of the user in question and my history as a moderator are irrelevant to that claim.

Comment: I don't know of any prior discussions that are analogous to this. But I do think that if there are questions of possible (subconscious) moderator bias involved in a heavy-handed decision that could have a large negative impact on contributions to this site, then that is something that is surely on-topic on meta. Of course I don't blame you for  being sympathetic to the plight of moderators in such circumstances. That's only natural considering you were a mod in the beginning, when the site was less stable.

Comment: @MathGems: You have been a member of this site for 2 days, so it is not surprising that you don't know of any prior discussions that are analogous to this.  It is surprising that you are willing to ascribe motivations to my actions based on what you claim the site was like 15+ months ago.

Comment: No, I have visited the site probably thousands of times, going way back to its inception.

Comment: BD has assured me that there are no other deleted comments, either by him or P. So could you please stop making speculations about such.

Comment: If that is true (that what is there now is what was there originally), it seems to me to be a minor disagreement and feelings were hurt. I realize we want to make people feel comfortable on a site like this and we are here to help, but surely, sooner or later offense will be taken. 30 days seems a steep sentence. Much worse things could have happened.